# How to use protractor to test Angular 4 nested components?

Tags: angular, protractor

My Angular 4 app's:

*index.html like this:*

```
<body>
  <app-main></app-main>
</body>
```

*main.component.html like this:*

```
<header>

  <app-menu></app-menu>

</header>
...
```

My question is: How to test locate the nested component?

*app.e2e-spec.ts*

```
 browser.get('http://localhost:4200/index.html');
 expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My Title');
```

How to locate a button in app-menu?

`element(by.css('app-main app-menu logo'))` not work.

Comment: does button have any id, class, name attributes?

Comment: Thank you, Kalamarico, fix my poor english and write style.

Comment: @Suresh I found the solution, use chain element locator to locate angular 4's nested component.

Answer (score 1):

After a short time after ask this question, I found the solution!

Use the chain locator to locate the nested components web elements.

```
    const menu = 
      element(by.tagName('app-main')).element(by.tagName('app-menu'));
    const logo = menu.element(by.css('logo'));
    expect(logo.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```